# WSoD in symfony2 any idea

Tags: php, linux, apache2, wsod

I tried to edit the php.ini in my server , apache2, and after editing it in putty I loaded both page , dev and production environment and noticed the white screen or blank page, no errors were displayed, what will I do , any help?

```
my edit : 

default:
memory_limit = 64M 

edited :

memory_limit = 128M
```

and edited it back to it's default because of the white screen but when I loaded again still nothing happens, . .

Comment: is there something in apache logs ?

Comment: @user801247 , you mean the error logs?

Comment: error log is a good starting point, access log might also be interesting

Comment: @user801247 - i've seen the error logs, but i suspect that the problem would be because i edited the memory_limit and that produces the white screen, not really sure . . any suggestion?

Comment: what do you have in your error log ? what happens if you rollback the memory_limit change or suppress the line ?

Comment: @user801247, tried to rollback the value of the memory_limit nothing happens though, and this would be the latest record in the error_log :     [Thu May 19 08:41:57 2016] [error] [client 192.120.203.210] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  Type in /tmxpage/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.1/tbl_properties_table_info.php
on line 16, referer: http://cbintranet3/phpMyAdmin-2.5.1/left.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112341/discussion-between-geekinthepink-and-user801247).